# Karate-Gatling: Is this possible to use karate features with Gatling Java DSL

Tags: karate

When I am trying to use the karate feature with the latest Gatling Java DSL, it is throwing an error while compiling for the karateFeature method

Answer (score 0):

No, we don't support the Gatling Java DSL yet. You are welcome to contribute code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will definitely look to contribute code for this.

Comment: @Deepak Did you find any working approach calling karateFeature() from Java? I tried many things to pass the expected varargs tags argument (empty). E.g.: `ScenarioBuilder defaultSimulation = scenario("Performance").exec((ActionBuilder) PreDef.karateFeature("classpath:perf.feature", Seq$.MODULE$.empty()));` But I always get: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateFeatureActionBuilder cannot be cast to class io.gatling.javaapi.core.ActionBuilder`.

Comment: @Peter I would expect that Java-to-Scala interoperability should work without adapting the Karate-Gatling Scala code. But also don't understand why I still can't get it to work (see my comment above).

Comment: @DrundaNibel I have nothing to add to my answer